# redirect to url but keep the root path

Tags: .htaccess

I redirected myurl.com/anythinghere1/anythinghere2/sid/KEY to myurl.com/file.php?KEY via

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/sid/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)$ file.php?sid=$3 [L]
```

that is working great. The new path myurl.com/anythinghere1/anythinghere2/sid/KEY is displayed in the browser URL as it should be. The main problem is that the file.php now has the new path /anythinghere1/anythinghere2/sid/ instead of the root path myurl.com/file.php and is displayed not correctly (path of images etc.). How could I define the original path myurl.com/file.php for the php file but keeping the displayed browser path myurl.com/anythinghere1/anythinghere2/sid/KEY?

if I use

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/sid/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)$ http\:\/\/www\.myurl\.com\/file.php?sid=$3 [L]
```

the browser path myurl.com/anythinghere1/anythinghere2/sid/KEY? is gone.

Thank you for your help in advance.